# Scala Code not executing

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to execute the following scala code on Spark but due to some reason the function selective is not getting called

```
var lines = sc.textFile(inputPath+fileName,1)
val lines2 =lines.map(l=>selective(
func,List(2,3),List(1,26),l,";",0           
))
lines2.toArray().foreach(l=>out.write(l))
.......
```

The selective function is defined as follows

```
def selective(f: (String,Boolean) => String , phoneFields: Seq[Int], codeFields: Seq[Int], in: String, delimiter:String, iMode:Int /* 0 for enc, 1 for dec */) :String =
        in.split(delimiter,-1).zipWithIndex
    .map { 

      case (str, ix) 
    if( phoneFields.contains(ix)||codeFields.contains(ix)) => 
        var output=f(str,codeFields.contains(ix))
        var sTemp=str+":"+output+"\n"
        if((iMode==0)&&codeFields.contains(ix)&&(str.compareTo("")!=0)  )
            CodeDictString+=sTemp
        else if(str.compareTo("")!=0)
            PhoneDictString+=sTemp

        output
      case other => other._1
    }.mkString(";").+("\n")
```

The println statement is not executing. Furthermore the function is not returning any thing.
sc is the spark context object

Comment: The information here is all on the wrong place. If `selective` isn't being called, then it's definition is irrelevant. Replace it with `l => { println(l); l }` -- if that doesn't show anything, then we the question should be about either [RDD's](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html) `map`, or about [SparkContext](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html). If it does, then `selective` _is_ being called, and you have to explain what it isn't doing that you expected it to.

Comment: And if we are to delve into `selective`, better to do it without the rest of the context. Describe `func`, and pass a simple string to it that should be working but isn't (such as one printed by the code in the previous comment).

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I just printed the number of lines before the map operation and that is a valid count . After that I replaced the map line above with the line lines.map(l=>{println(l);l}) and it does not print any thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does not compile. The syntax

```
{
  some statement
  case ... => ...
```

is not valid. Case statements can *only* appear like this:

```
{
   case ... => ...
       ...
   case ... => ...
       ...
}
```

Since you obviously got *something* to compile, I bet there's a case statement before that `println`, and that case statement is not being selected.

Comment: I have updated the post and complete code for the selective function is there. There is no case statement before the println

Comment: I am not sure of the exact error but a bit of restructuring of the code as mentioned by you and making some other changes solved the problem. One other thing is that map operations in spark returns a new RDD, it does not change the original RDD. So I am marking your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @Raza My answer really doesn't apply. I suggest you answer your own question, based on what you learned.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running this in `local` mode or on a cluster?  The function passed to `lines.map` is evaluated by the Spark workers, so that println will appear in the worker's stdout logs if you're running on a cluster (these logs are viewable via Spark's web UI).

Comment: No I am running on local machine

Comment: What output _do_ you see?  Could `lines` be empty, by chance?

Comment: I have checked that lines are not empty. I am saving the lines to a file after applying the selective function. Size of the output file is zero. So I wanted to first of all make sure that selective function is  being called.

Comment: Are you invoking an action (like collect(), toArray(), take(), or count()) on your RDD to trigger computation?  Spark's transformations are lazy and your map function won't be evaluated until an action is performed.

Comment: @Raza: In Spark, the execution of transformations only occurs when _actions_ are performed (see the [RDD Operations section of Spark's Scala Programming Guide](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/scala-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations)).  If my Spark program contained only the line `val myRdd = sc.textFile(...).map(l=>{println(l);l})`, then nothing would be printed.  I would have to call an action like `myRDD.count()` or `myRDD.collect()` to trigger the computation.  This laziness allows Spark to make various optimizations, including pipelining of things like *.map().map()...

Comment: I think I am making some other gross mistake. I did as you mentioned that after lines = sc.textFile().map(l=>{println(l);l}) I added lines.collect() but it still does not print the lines though lines.count shows 3326