# Spark job for twitter streaming is not giving any output

Tags: apache-spark, twitter, spark-streaming, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to run a twitter streaming job with spark as master with the below code  and not getting any output. Job is being paused for so much time. Could someone please help in resolving the issue. This program is running perfect in local mode & Yarn as master and giving me the exact output what i want. But in spark master, its not behaving as expected.

```
package org.test.scala

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._

object twitterAnalysis {

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("twitter sentiment analysis")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val filters = args

    for(i <- filters) { println("recieved arg" + i) }

    /* setting up the Twitter4j library parameters */        
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", mykey)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", mysecret)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", acesskey)
    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accesssecret)

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc,Seconds(5))

    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,None,filters)

    //stream.print()

    val hashtags = stream.flatMap( status => status.getText.split(" ").filter( _.startsWith("#")) ) 

    println("here are the elements of HashTags")
   // hashtags.print()

    val topcounts60 = hashtags.map((_,1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _ ,Seconds(60))
                     .map { case (topic,count) => (count,topic) }
                     .transform(_.sortByKey(false))

    topcounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
        val toplist = rdd.take(10)
        println("\n Popular topics in last 10 seconds ( %s total) ".format(rdd.count()))
        toplist.foreach { case (count,tag)  => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }

        })
   ssc.start
    ssc.awaitTermination

  }

}
```

Upon hitting this with command

```
bin/spark-submit –class org.test.scala.twitterAnalysis –master spark://localhost.localdomain:7077 –jars <dependency jarlocation> jar name
```

the job is getting hold and not giving me any output.
 Below are the terminal output and  STDERR log

Terminal output

```
[edureka@localhost spark-1.5.2]$ bin/spark-submit --class org.test.scala.twitterAnalysis --master spark://localhost.localdomain:7077 --jars file:///home/edureka/TransferredJars/twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar  /home/edureka/TransferredJars/twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar #apple #spark #currency #iphone
16/11/20 15:48:31 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.2
16/11/20 15:48:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/20 15:48:32 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, localhost.localdomain resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.0.107 instead (on interface eth3)
16/11/20 15:48:32 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
16/11/20 15:48:32 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: edureka
16/11/20 15:48:32 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: edureka
16/11/20 15:48:32 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(edureka); users with modify permissions: Set(edureka)
16/11/20 15:48:34 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/11/20 15:48:34 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.0.107:38060]
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 38060.
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-521ff84c-473d-4c91-b675-933a02fc6cf4
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 534.5 MB
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO spark.HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-1e434766-f32a-4608-92a0-2207b4a52727/httpd-29639e5c-b536-432a-888a-396eb60a60cb
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO spark.HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/11/20 15:48:35 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:56724
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 56724.
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/11/20 15:48:36 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.0.107:4040
16/11/20 15:48:44 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:///home/edureka/TransferredJars/twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar at http://192.168.0.107:56724/jars/twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar with timestamp 1479637124496
16/11/20 15:48:44 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/edureka/TransferredJars/twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar at http://192.168.0.107:56724/jars/twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar with timestamp 1479637124520
16/11/20 15:48:44 WARN metrics.MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
16/11/20 15:48:44 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://localhost.localdomain:7077...
16/11/20 15:48:45 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20161120154845-0000
16/11/20 15:48:45 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20161120154845-0000/0 on worker-20161120154741-192.168.0.107-42431 (192.168.0.107:42431) with 1 cores
16/11/20 15:48:45 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20161120154845-0000/0 on hostPort 192.168.0.107:42431 with 1 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
16/11/20 15:48:45 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20161120154845-0000/0 is now RUNNING
16/11/20 15:48:46 INFO client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20161120154845-0000/0 is now LOADING
16/11/20 15:48:47 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 38621.
16/11/20 15:48:47 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 38621
16/11/20 15:48:47 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/11/20 15:48:47 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.0.107:38621 with 534.5 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.107, 38621)
16/11/20 15:48:47 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/11/20 15:48:48 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
here are the elements of HashTags
16/11/20 15:48:52 WARN util.SizeEstimator: Failed to check whether UseCompressedOops is set; assuming yes
```

And below is the snapshot of STDERR log in spark UI

```
16/11/20 15:52:36 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637356400
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(15589) called with curMem=12488978, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637356800 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 15.2 KB, free 522.6 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:37 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637356800 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637356800
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(7069) called with curMem=12504567, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637357000 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.9 KB, free 522.6 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:37 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637357000 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637357000
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(47183) called with curMem=12511636, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637357200 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 46.1 KB, free 522.6 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:37 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637357200 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637357200
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3424) called with curMem=12558819, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637357400 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.3 KB, free 522.6 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:37 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637357400 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637357400
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(4630) called with curMem=12562243, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637357600 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 4.5 KB, free 522.5 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:37 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637357600 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:37 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637357600
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(10421) called with curMem=12566873, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637357800 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 10.2 KB, free 522.5 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:38 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637357800 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637357800
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(44965) called with curMem=12577294, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637358000 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 43.9 KB, free 522.5 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:38 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637358000 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637358000
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(6376) called with curMem=12622259, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637358200 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.2 KB, free 522.5 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:38 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637358200 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:38 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637358200
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(10971) called with curMem=12628635, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637358800 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 10.7 KB, free 522.5 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:39 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637358800 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637358800
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2507) called with curMem=12639606, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637359000 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.4 KB, free 522.5 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:39 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637359000 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO receiver.BlockGenerator: Pushed block input-0-1479637359000
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(45512) called with curMem=12642113, maxMem=560497950
16/11/20 15:52:39 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block input-0-1479637359200 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 44.4 KB, free 522.4 MB)
16/11/20 15:52:39 WARN storage.BlockManager: Block input-0-1479637359200 replicated to only 0 peer(s) instead of 1 peers
```

the log is continuously growing like above. Request you to help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Code not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696858/scala-code-not-executing)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. The problem given in the link is different. Here the code is getting executed. We can observe that STDERR log provided in the question. But the problem is not getting any output and job keeps on running.

Comment: I think it is exactly the same problem. Please read carefully answer by Josh Rosen http://stackoverflow.com/a/19697469/6022341